# Copiar DLL para diretório com .nuspec sem referenciá-la no projeto

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Criei um NuGet local. Funcionou bem, até encontrarmos um problema que não consigo resolver de pronto. O seguinte: Existe uma referência no projeto, que chama outra referência. Bem, acontece que essa referência não pode ser adicionada como referência, mas essa `DLL` deve estar no mesmo diretório(pasta) que a `DLL` referenciada. Se eu coloco assim:
`<file src="...." target="minha_pasta" />` ela entra como referência. O que eu quero é mover essa `DLL`, que não deve entrar como referência no pacote, para o diretório em que a `DLL` de referência está. Veja como está meu *.nuspec*.

```
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>NetRelatorios.Site.Paulo</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <authors>Tecnologia</authors>
        <description>01.SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site (Camada de apresentação)</description>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site/AjaxControlToolkit/4.1.50731.0/AjaxControlToolkit.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site/Interop.Shell32/1.0.0.0/Interop.Shell32.dll" target="lib/net40" /> 
        <file src="SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms/11.0.3442.2/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="SisAmilNetRelatorios.Site/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms/10.0.40219.1/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.configuration.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Data.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Drawing.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.ServiceProcess.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.DynamicData.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.Entity.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.Extensions.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.Services.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.EnterpriseServices.dll" target="lib/net40" />
        <file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll" target="lib/net40" />
    </files>    
</package>
```

Esta `DLL` não deve entrar como referência. Devo apenas copiar ela para o mesmo diretório, só isso. Só preciso copiar para o mesmo diretório dessa `DLL`.

```
<file src="NETFramework/v4.0/System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" target="lib/net40" />
```

Answer (score 1):

O que eu quero é impossível. A própria natureza do NuGet não permite, ou seja, se é DLL e está na pasta em que o NuGet busca, vai ser instalada. Caso haja a necessidade de ter uma situação semelhante a que foi postada, infelizmente alguém terá que colocar a DLL na mão na pasta, após a instalação pelo NuGet.